# Elasticsearch data dump as json

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

we have a ES 2.4 cluster containing 50k records. I would like a dump of that as csv or json of specific fields. How to handle the size field as it allows only 10k records.

Note: We have a new 8.x cluster reingesting data from source. we are looking for a way to check if all the data is there in the new cluster.

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 30,
  "fields":["code","version","locales"],
  "aggs": {
    "code_version_count": {
      "cardinality": {
        "script": "doc['code'].value + ' ' + doc['version'].value"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `from`  and `size` to iterate over:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/search-request-from-size.html

```
{
    "from" : 0, "size" : 10,
    "query" : {
        "term" : { "user" : "kimchy" }
    }
}
```

or use the Scroll API:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/search-request-scroll.html

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/_search?scroll=1m' -d '
{
    "query": {
        "match" : {
            "title" : "elasticsearch"
        }
    }
}
'
```

The scroll parameter will return a scroll_id  you must use to get the next batch of results :

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_search/scroll' -d' 
{
    "scroll" : "1m", 
    "scroll_id" : "c2Nhbjs2OzM0NDg1ODpzRlBLc0FXNlNyNm5JWUc1" 
}
'
```

To dump CSV or JSON you must develop your own script, or you can also use a tool for this, like elasticsearch-dump:

https://github.com/elasticsearch-dump/elasticsearch-dump